# jQuery cant find element on ngView loaded elements [AngularJS]

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I m trying to get `offset().top` of an element `<div class='profile'></div>` present in a `ngView` controlled by *app.js* but the console displays an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined

**jQuery code :**

```
var topOfOthDiv = $('.profile').offset().top;
```

**index.ejs**

```
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="main/js/main.js"></script>
    ...
</head>
    <body>
       <div class="ui inverted top fixed nbar hidden menu">...</div>
       <div class="ui main container " ng-view>
       </div>
    </body>
```

**main.js**

```
$(document)
    .ready(function() {

        var topOfOthDiv = $('.profile').offset().top;
        $(window).scroll(function() {
                if($(window).scrollTop() > topOfOthDiv) { //scrolled past the other div?
                    $('.fixed.menu').transition('fade in'); //reached the desired point -- show div
                }
                if($(window).scrollTop() < topOfOthDiv) { //scrolled past the other div?
                    $('.fixed.menu').transition('fade out'); //reached the desired point -- show div
                }
            });
    })
  ;
```

In `ng-view` i load my different view which has `.profile` clss div
The code works fine if `.profile` class is in index.ejs

Comment: have you loaded jquery correctly?

Comment: Can you provide sample plunkr?

Comment: yes i loaded it correctly.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/joshdmiller/NEuJ6/
not working :|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, without looking at the entire code we can't really tell why, because this could be a number of reasons, however the most likely reason is:

1. You're loading the Javascript file *after* you declare your `HTML`. This means the script is looking for something that is written to the browser after execution.
2. You've not loaded jQuery properly.

Comment: I am loading `main.js` and jquery in `head` and the code works fine if i use `.profile` class in `index.ejs` but not in ng-views. I added few more codes!